# Offering a default on return in a shell script input prompt

Tags: shell, default, prompt

I inappropriately asked my question on 'How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?'

I've gone through the 'Questions with similar titles' list and cannot see an answer.

I obviously don't have bash4 as the following doesn't work:

```
$ read -e -p "Enter database SID, or just return for default: " -i "swmfolx" ORACLE_SID 
-bash: read: -i: invalid option 
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]
```

'All' I am trying to do is prompt for input with the option of just return for the default.

Any links or advice would be gratefully acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do this as follows:

```
read -p "Enter database SID: " dbsid
if [ "$dbsid" = "" ]
then
    dbsid="mydefaultvalue"
fi
```

...essentially, read the value and if all they've done is hit enter, it assigns the default value.